# Groß-/Kleinschreibung von "jahrzehnte alt"

Tags: spelling, capitalization

Wie ist in den folgenden Sätzen die Groß- bzw. Kleinschreibung korrekt?

#### A:

> Diese Jahrzehnte alte Idee ist toll.

Ein *Jahrzehnt* ist ein Substantiv, daher müsste es großgeschrieben werden; aber gilt dies in Verbindung mit dem Adjektiv "alt" immer noch, oder muss es so heißen:

#### B:

> Diese jahrzehnte-alte Idee ist toll.

Ist der Bindestrich hier richtig oder falsch?

Comment: Irgendwie ist mein Internet kaputt, Duden und ngram versagen regelrecht, aber [das hier](www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/jahrzehntealt) spuckt mir Google aus. Ich hoffe es existiert.

Comment: Aber auch ohne Quellen: *jahrzehnte* alleine existiert nicht als Adjektiv. Es kann nicht irgendetwas *jahrzehnt* sein. Und Bindestrich, naja, werden im Deutschen eh schon zu viel gesetzt. Also lassen wir es auch hier bleiben. Und wie würdest du es mit Tag, Woche und Monat machen? Daher kannst du auch deine Variante A nehmen. Ich würde grundsätzlich zu A tendieren, aber B ist nicht falsch. (ohne Komma versteht sich)

Comment: @Em1: Ich bin mir nicht sicher was Du sagen willst: Meinst Du nun "Jahrzehnte alt" oder "jahrzehntealt" ist korrekt(er)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In der unbestimmten Bedeutung wird *jahrzehntealt* als Adjektiv zusammengeschrieben und somit kleingeschrieben:

> Diese jahrzehntealte Idee ist toll.

Die Getrenntschreibung ist nur richtig, wenn eine nähere Bestimmung hinzukommt: *drei, mehrere, viele Jahrzehnte alt.*

> Diese viele Jahrzehnte alte Idee ist toll.

Comment: Klingt logisch. Danke.

Comment: Was sagt die neue Rechtschreibung dazu? Ich halte es für wahrscheinlich, dass die Schreibung *diese Jahrzehnte alte Idee* (ohne die Mengenangabe davor) inzwischen erlaubt ist.

Comment: @Wolf Bin mir nicht sicher. Habe aber etwas gefunden: http://www.korrekturen.de/nachgefragt/jahrhunderte_alt_oder_jahrhundertealt.shtml

Comment: Aufschlussreicher Fund. Vielleicht solltest du deine Antwort etwas aufweichen bezüglich der Getrenntschreibung?

Answer (score -1):

"Jahrzehnt" ist eine Einheit und daher groß zu schreiben:

> Die Straße ist vier **Meter** breit.
>   Der Motor hat eine Leistung von fünftausend **Watt**.
>   Das Gewitter hat nur fünf **Minuten** gedauert.

und daher auch:

> Mein Auto ist nun schon drei **Jahrzehnte** alt.
>   Dieses mehrere **Jahrzehnte** alte Auto fährt noch immer.
>   Hans hat auch ein **Jahrzehnte** altes Auto.

Vergleiche auch mit:

> Auf der A9 bildet sich ein **Kilometer** langer Stau.

Comment: Wie stehts dann mit dem von Em1 vorgeschlagenen [Duden-Eintrag](http://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/jahrzehntealt)?

Comment: splattne's Antwort zu Folge sind die letzten beiden Sätze übrigens falsch ;)